# Не могу добавить элементы формы на splitContainer

Tags: c#, winforms

Не могу добавить элементы формы на `splitContainer`.

Пишу:

```
 splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(button1);
```

Но кнопка остается позади панели.

Comment: Если можно, скиньте проєкт. У меня работаєт. Ви расположения кнопки устанавливали?

Comment: Попробуйте так: `splitContainer1.Panel1.Controls.Add(button1);
            button1.Left = 0;
            button1.Top = 0;`